# constructing json from multiple tables in codeigniter with active record or mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, activerecord

I have 3 tables:

- creators
- projects
- project_galleries

where each creator will have a list of projects identified by their "creator_id" being the "id" in the creator table, and each project, if it is of type "gallery" will have a list of project_galleries identified by their "project_id" being the "id" in the project table.

I want to output a json file like this:

```
{
  "creators" : [
    name: "creator1",
    projects: [
      { 
        name: "project1",
        type: "video" //no need to get project gallery here
      },
      {
        name: "project2",
        type: "gallery",
        gallery_images: [
          {
             image: "01.jpg",
             caption: "01 caption"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I can sort of get what I need with this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('1985_creators');
$this->db->join('1985_projects','1985_projects.creator_id = 1985_creators.id');
$this->db->join('1985_project_galleries','1985_project_galleries.project_id = 1985_projects.id','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

and my controller simply does this:

```
$data['json'] = $this->creators_model->get_all_creator_data();
$this->load->view('data/json_data', $data);
```

with a view like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

if(isset($json)) {
    echo json_encode($json);
}
else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}
```

But there is no "grouping" which I need for the json - I just end up with a list of all projects or galleries. How would I achieve the json structure above?  I read something in the docs about a compiled select which might be applicable, but I'm not quite sure how to use it. Or maybe my controller needs to make some sort of loop?

Comment: I could recommend using [MY_Model](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model) introduced by Adrian Voicu and based on Jamie Rumbelow's my_model. Very neat way to get models/tables related and have data from those. Using, it will return you array of wanted structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I could find to do this was:

```
public function get_all_creator_data(){
    $creators = $this->creators_model->get_creators_content();
    foreach ($creators as $h=>$creator){
        $creators[$h]['projects'] = $this->creators_model->get_projects_data($creator['id']);
        foreach($creators[$h]['projects'] as $i=>$project){
            if ($project['type'] == "gallery"){
                $creators[$h]['projects'][$i]['gallery'] = $this->creators_model->get_gallery_data($project['id']);
            }
        }
    }

    $data['json'] = $creators;
    $this->load->view('data/json_data', $data);

}

//MODEL

public function get_creators_content(){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('1985_creators',array('active' => 1));
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function get_projects_data($creator_id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('1985_projects',array('creator_id' => $creator_id ));
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function get_gallery_data($project_id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('1985_project_galleries',array('project_id' => $project_id ));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```